# Roku: Random flickering when Dialog is shown?

Tags: dialog, flicker, roku

I have a dialog that randomly flickers when it is shown. There doesn't seem to be a lot of clues as to why it is doing so. It will flicker for a couple of seconds, then stop, then it will flicker again randomly, etc. When it flickers there is ~ a 1 sec input lag from the remote to the app. When the flickering stops it is back to its normal responsiveness. Anyone one else experience this?

```
dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
dialog.optionsDialog = true
dialog.titleColor = "0xffffff"
dialog.messageColor = "0xffffff"
dialog.dividerUri = ""

dialog.width = "900"
dialog.title = "Exit App"
dialog.message = "Are you sure you want to exit?"
dialog.buttons = ["Cancel","Exit"]
dialog.buttonGroup.minWidth = "40"
dialog.buttonGroup.maxWidth = "40"
dialog.buttonGroup.focusedIconUri = ""
dialog.buttonGroup.iconUri = ""

dialog.observeField("buttonSelected", "onExitDialogButtonClick")

m.top.dialog = dialog
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a problem with the texture memory.
You should check how much texture memory is used. You can read on how to do that [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/4266017)

Comment: That's what I kinda leaned toward but I used `loaded_textures` cmd and it wasn't close to the limit 
`Texture Memory: 6090KB of 41943KB used`

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with the code you provided but that's only the part of the code that is creating dialog object. Is it possible that "flicker" is actually new Dialog being created? Maybe you are creating multiple dialogs for some reason that is beyond the code you have provided? That input lag is what give me this idea.